# Take character and return the Keypad equivalant

Tags: java

So I am writing code that will take a character and return its alpha-numeric keypad equivalent as a character. 
The problem is, I am getting a question mark in a box as a return. I have checked that the input is correct. For example, with a char 'h' input, i should get a char '4' return. Hoping someone is able to spot my error.
Code is below:

```
public char getDigit(char letter) throws Exception{

    switch (letter) {           
    case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case '2':
        return 2;
    case 'd': case 'e': case 'f': case '3':
        return 3;
    case 'g': case 'h': case 'i': case '4':
        return 4;
    case 'j': case 'k': case 'l': case '5':
        return 5;
    case 'm': case 'n': case 'o': case '6':
        return 6;
    case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': case '7':
        return 7;
    case 't': case 'u': case 'v': case '8':
        return 8;
    case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z': case '9':
        return 9;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a letter or number on the Alpha-Numeric Keypad.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure @GhostCat, My apologies and Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of your method is **char**.

Now take your switch statement. You return char values in the range from 2 to 9. Now look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Surprise: these chars are all "unprintable" control characters. Thus your console gives you "?" when you print them!

If you want '4', your code has to return '4', not 4! Or 52, because that entry in the ASCII table represents '4'.

Comment: GhostCat, Thankyou. Such a simple thing... Changed to '4' and everything works.

Comment: @JustinHayden Just for the record: you could also return `'0' + 4` . ('0' is 48, + 4 makes it 52, makes it '4' ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting proper output because you are using `char` as a return type of `getDigit(..)` function. **You should use `int` as a return type instead of `char`** as in switch case you are comparing with characters and returning digit values So replace your code with the following code, this will work:

```
public int getDigit(char letter) throws Exception{

switch (letter) {           
case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case '2':
    return 2;
case 'd': case 'e': case 'f': case '3':
    return 3;
case 'g': case 'h': case 'i': case '4':
    return 4;
case 'j': case 'k': case 'l': case '5':
    return 5;
case 'm': case 'n': case 'o': case '6':
    return 6;
case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': case '7':
    return 7;
case 't': case 'u': case 'v': case '8':
    return 8;
case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z': case '9':
    return 9;
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a letter or number on the Alpha-Numeric Keypad.");
}
}
```

Comment: Another nice answer, pointing out the other way to go here ;-)